# nodejs fs.openSync() with the flags 'a' fails to create a non-exist file

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to write a log module for my app, which will create a non-exist file according to the time the module is initialized (with the init function in the module is called).

However, when I try to create the new log file with `fs.openSync(log_file_name,'a')` It always gets an error.

I appreciate anyone that tell me why it fails to create the new file .

```
const fs=require('fs');
const path=require('path');
const moment=require('moment');
var time=function()
{
    return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD[_]hh:mm:ss:SSS');
};

//init
var fd; // file descriptor

function init(log_dir)
{
    var log_file_name=path.join(log_dir,time()+'.log');
    this.fd=fs.openSync(log_file_name,'a');
}
init(__dirname);
```

The error is like below:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2016.1\bin\runnerw.exe"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" index.js
fs.js:634
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open    'I:\twesix\lib\twesix_nodejs\log\2016-05-19_01:34:52:621.log'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
at init (I:\twesix\lib\twesix_nodejs\log\index.js:15:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (I:\twesix\lib\twesix_nodejs\log\index.js:24:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using windows 10 and my node.js version is 6.1.0

Comment: do you have a valid value for time()+'.log' ?

Comment: console.log(log_file_name) gets I:\twesix\lib\twesix_nodejs\log\2016-05-19_01:52:28:776.log. Does this file name have any invalid character or something else?

Comment: that's right, the colons are not valid in file names on windows. I just wrote the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the string returned by `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD[_]hh:mm:ss:SSS');` contains colons (`:`), which are not allowed in the name of the files on windows.

Change the `format()` to something that doesn't contain invalid characters for windows file names, like:

```
return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD[_]hh-mm-ss-SSS');
```